# jQuery selector: finding table cell based on content

Tags: jquery, html-table, cell

I'm trying to select a table cell which contains specific text but couldn't find out yet how it works:
I'm having this code - but doesn't work:

```
var td = $("td:contains('MyCell')",tbl);
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: That should work. Could you provide some more context for your code and your HTML?

Comment: are you using the 2nd argument in $() correctly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The example code below worked for me. Hope it helps....

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function getCell( cell )
{
    var cell || '';
    var result = $('tr').find('td:contains('+cell+')');

    alert( $(result).text() );
}
```

```
 <body onload="javascript:getCell('cell 4');">

 <table width="30" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
    <td>cell 1</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
    <td>cell 3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>cell 4</td>
    <td>cell 5</td>
    <td>cell 6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>cell 7</td>
    <td>cell 8</td>
    <td>cell 9</td>
</tr>
 </table>


 </body>
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe instead of the second parameter `tbl`

```
var td = $("#mySpecificTable td:contains('MyCell')");
```

Comment: Quick and efficient approach!

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure, "MyCell" is inside the cell and not its class name or an attribute of the `<td>`, right?

Another possibility is the `:contains()` selector is case sensitive so if the content is "myCell" the selector wouldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried without the ''? as in

```
var td = $("td:contains(MyCell)",tbl);
```