# Get Parent Table name using Text present in td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am developing an MVC app in which I have created two tables in view dynamically. In each table first column contains ID and last column contains save button. On click of save button I'm passing this ID to my function. Now I want to check the button was clicked from which table so that I can perform operations. I have tried many solutions but did not work. Can anybody help?

```
function SaveDocument(_param) {
//alert(_param + "Add");
return;
var tableRow = $("td").filter(function () {
    return $(this).text() == String(_param);
}).parent('tr');
tableRow.parent().attr('uid');
}
```

and I have also tried links like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082927/jquery-selector-finding-table-cell-based-on-content) but none of these work.

Edit : -
I have created fiddle for this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Rohitk124/hn2n5y3q/)

Comment: `$(this).closest('table')`

Comment: @Rayon I tried this too but it does not work

Comment: Can you share a fiddle of the same ?

Comment: Well It's little lengthy so I won't be possible as I had to create dummy data for it and then put it.

Comment: I'm just saying that it would take time to do it also I'm also working on it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114934/discussion-between-rohit-and-rayon).

Comment: @Rayon I have added jsfiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/hn2n5y3q/1/

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you're creating tables dynamically, so I'm assuming your click event won't fire unless you delegate it.

Try adding a class say `.save` to the buttons and run the below code.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.save', function(){
  console.log($(this).closest('table'));
});
```